# C# - How do I know the correct length to read a string when reading it from a memory address?

Tags: c#, intptr, readprocessmemory

So I have a problem: I'm reading a string from a memory address that is different at different times. For example:

```
Axe?ca Ocarina?tar??ing?ing????????????
```

I only need Axe.

```
Ball of Green Yarn??ing?ing????????????
```

I only need Ball of Green Yarn.

I'm reading 80 bytes of text (40 chars) because that's the most amount of characters the string should get to. But how can I know how long the string actually is?

Comment: prolly(if it is C style string) by chcecking byte by byte and compare it byte = 0 ... also there is a function for reading C style UTF8 strings `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what's writing the string.

Generally, strings are NUL-terminated, i.e. a `'\0'` character immediately follows the string.  Old-style *(non-`_s`-variant)* C functions like `strlen` and `strcat` use that to determine the end of existing strings and mark the end of modified strings.

*Most* string data types tend to work this way, but not all.  In Turbo Pascal, strings were length-prefixed.  `BSTR`s used in COM (including pre-.NET VB) are both.

Based on the samples you've shown, there's a good chance that the `?` character you're seeing after the part you want is a NUL character.  It looks like the buffer is being reused and re-terminated each time, e.g. a shorter string like "Axe" was written over a longer string like a certain kind of ocarina.

Examine the buffer in the debugger and you'll probably find a `'\0'` character immediately following what you want.

**Probably.**  Again, it depends on what's writing the string.  Until you look for yourself, it could be anything, and even then, it could just be a coincidence that it's NUL-terminated *this time*.  Don't rely on observation alone.  Without documentation, it could be different and still just as valid.  **Whatever you do**, *do not read past the 40-character buffer you know you have*, NUL terminated or not.